# Change mail subject with sieve based on content

Tags: email, dovecot, sieve

I have a mailserver with dovecot and sieve enabled.

My bank sends me a mail when an incoming/ougoing transaction is made. However, it's a general subject "Transaction occured", the actual account is mentioned in the email body.

Can I change the subject based on the content of the mail?

I have found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1502588/how-to-change-a-messages-subject-in-a-sieve-rule), but it's not about message body.

I would like to avoid having a script running that will change the mails either on disk or via IMAP download/reupload.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup will need the Sieve [Body extension](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5173) - this lets you write conditions on the email body using the `body` statement.

As for subject line editing, [the answer you mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/1502589) worked for me recently.